# How to set custom value as max value on CGAffineTransformation?

Tags: iphone, ios, cgaffinetransform

I'm working on gauge graph. I'm using CGAffineTransformation for rotating the arrow. It accepts value in radians. There I want to use different value. Like 180 is max so i want to assign it some value say 1000. n if i pass value say 700 to CGAffineTransformation, the arrow should rotate till 700. Please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `modulo operation` ?
Try using [fmod()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/) (don't forget to #import <tgmath.h>)

```
  float val = fmod(700, 180); // val would be '160'
```